# No puedo crear un formulario en c++ usando sharpdevelop

Tags: c++

Hola quiero crear un formulario pero para c++ el problema esque no puedo os muestro una imagen de los objetos que si puedo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esque quiero un ide parecido a visualstudio pero por lo menos que pueda crear mis propios formularios en c++ y hasta el momento no lo he consigo he intentando usar sharpdevelop a ver si funciona pero no funciono conozco qt pero normalmente tengo que usar librerias estaticas para transportar mi aplicación por lo que hubiese sido util conocer otro método diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El estándar de c++ no dispone de ninguna alternativa para crear aplicaciones de escritorio. Llegados a este punto únicamente hay dos posibilidades:

- haces uso de la API del sistema operativo para crear las ventanas
- recurres a una librería de terceros que te proporcione esta característica.

Yo te sugeriría la opción de la librería, ya que las APIs no suelen ser muy amigables.

A tu disposición tienes bastantes opciones, yo te enumero solo algunas de las más comunes:

- [Qt](https://www.qt.io/es/): es un framework completo para Qt. Entre sus múltiples utilidades
  dispone de un conjunto de controles gráficos bastante completo. Tiene
  hasta su propio IDE.
- [wxWidget](http://www.wxwidgets.org/): está librería se centra más en ofrecer
  un entorno gráfico.
- [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/): Evolución de la librería gráfica GTK.

Las tres opciones son multiplataforma.

Comment: tambien existen version antiguas de visual que son mucho más rapidas que la actual al final y al cabo uno tiene que decidir entre qt o visual studio o sino irse por gtk+ o wxwidget pero como dice el otro compañero es bastante engorroso y poco recomendable a principiantes

Comment: @Perl si te refieres a las MFC no las he comentado porque no son multiplataforma y a mi modo de ver son obsoletas

Answer (score 1):

a formulario te refieres a Windows Forms lo único que  se me ocurre es codeblocks con wxwidget o GTK+ pero su implementación es engorrosa yo lo intente en el pasado pero siempre regresaba a visual studio